How to Translate Month and Day Names in Material-UI DateTimePicker (v7.13.0)?
I'm using Material-UI's DateTimePicker component in my project, specifically version 7.13.0. I need to translate the names of the months and days of the week to a different language (e.g., Spanish). I've tried using the LocalizationProvider with the appropriate locale, but the month and day names still appear in English.
Here's a simplified version of my current implementation:
import React from "react";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterMoment } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterMoment";
import { DesktopDateTimePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { esES } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/locales";

export default function MyDateTimePicker() {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider
      dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}
      localeText={esES.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}
      adapterLocale="es"
    >
      <DesktopDateTimePicker
        label="Select Date and Time"
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

Despite this setup, the month and day names remain in English. How can I properly translate these names to Spanish or any other language using Material-UI's DateTimePicker?
Is there a specific configuration or additional step that I might be missing?
Thanks in advance!

Refering to the MUI X docs:

For moment, import the locale and then pass its name to LocalizationProvider

And their example:
import { AdapterMoment } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterMoment';
import 'moment/locale/de';

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment} adapterLocale="de">
  {children}
</LocalizationProvider>;

So in your code there is only one line missing:
import 'moment/locale/es';


<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} adapterLocale={de} localeText={deDE.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}> works for me.

You are right, it's different for every library adapter. The Mui docs describe it for each one of them.
